# Finding nth nearest neighbors of each point

Tags: matlab

I have distance between some points in an N by N matrix called `M`. `M(i,j)` is the distance between point `i` and `j`. Of course, `M` is a symmetric matrix.I want a vector `C`, `C(i)` shows the distance between particle number i and its 7th neighbour.

What is the best way (less time consuming) to do that? (N is very large and I want to do this in a for loop). Could anyone help me please?
7th neighbour of point number `i` is 7th point which is close to `i` (close in distance).

Comment: How do you define the "7th" neighbor?

Comment: 7th neighbour of point number i is 7th point which is close to i.

Comment: It's still not very clear to me what is the 7th point - is it up or down, left/right from i? What happens in the last column/row?

Comment: distanceS between points are in matrix M. noTE THAT BY close distance I don't mean distance in arrays. Note to definition of M in question. Distances are in matrix M. Is it clear?

Comment: Is it clear? @atru

Comment: Not quite, the definition of M and C is clear to me, the problem is the 7th neighbor. How do you determine that - or is the determination part of the problem?

Comment: yes it is part of problem. But definition of 7th neighbour of i is 7th point which is close to i in distance. Is it clear? @atru

Comment: Yep. Now it's clear - 7th closest point, i.e. further than 6th, 5th etc. but closer than 8th..? First thing that crossed my mind when I saw this were atomistic simulations with regular lattices where you have multiple points with the same distance. Hence a bit of confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first sort the distances for each point

```
dist_srt = sort(M)
```

And then extract the 7th distance for each point (i.e. entire 7th row of `M`)

```
dist_neigh = dist_srt(7,:)
```

This doesn't take advantage of the fact that M is symmetric - you should consider doing that if you run into performance issues.